# Not receiving any e-mails after new comment

Tags: comments, email, notifications

I know this has been asked several times before in the past, but I think my situation is a bit unique.

I am not receiving any e-mails when someone leaves a comment on my posts. Neither are any of the other authors at the site.

1. I have set the correct e-mail address in my user account and the
   general settings.
2. I have checked the two "send mail" fields under discussion settings
3. I am able to receive other e-mails from the site such as user
   registration and forgotten password.
4. I have tried installing an add-on to notify a user of replies to 
   comment. That works fine.
5. I have tried uninstalling my spam shield and other plugins, but that
   changed nothing.
6. I have tried changing theme, but that also did not work
7. I have installed a mail logger, and that shows me that the comment
   mails are indeed not being sent, whereby it is not due to my own web
   client/spam folder. The mail logger works fine, it logs all the
   before mentioned mails which are being sent.

I have tried looking for an addon which can replicate the default behavior, but such an addon does not seem to exist.

Any way to debug it? Or do anyone have a fix?

Comment: Are you sure that this is not somekind of spam blocker on your server. I can remember having this issue once, and eventually I found that my host blocked my emails as spam. Usually, these spam blockers are very sensitive and trigger for nothing, causing this silent failure in mail sending

Comment: Yes, nothing is being sent out it seems. But all my other WPmails works.